# Magento won't let me execute files

Tags: magento-1.7, rhel5

I have magento in `public_html`

In `/public_html/affiliate` I have copied app files for a third-party tool. When I try to run `/public_html/affiliate/install/index.php` I get a magento "The page you requested was not found." page.

It was working but the installer failed, and now I can't even run it again or any thing in those directories. Not sure what changed. And not sure where to look.

Also I can't even run `/public_html/affiliate/phpinfo.php`

**EDIT**
Ok this is more strange.
I created a new folder `/public_html/afftest`
and put `phpinfo.php` in it.

Why am I able to execute `phpinfo.php` in `/public_html/afftest`, but not the copy in `/public_html/affiliate`?

They have identical owner, group and permissions.

Also if I rename `/affiliate` to `/xaffiliate` I still can't run the `phpinfo.php` inside.

What the heck is going on!?

Comment: Are you actually adding 'public_html' into your URL when you try and access the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some kind of permissions issue!

this resolved it

```
find -type f -name ‘*.php’ -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your webserver has the wrong path setup.

Are you sure the phpinfo.php which is run when you visit the document root is the actual one in the folder you are referring to?

It could be the case the document root is pointing to some other default location which happens to have a phpinfo.php and that is being run, so when you add folders it's looking in the wrong place.

Try editing your phpinfo.php file and adding something at the top such as

you can then confirm the document root is actually in the right location.